Hanging indents for cventry and cvitem in moderncv?
Is there a way to set small hanging indents (indents starting on the second line) within cvitem and cventry commands in moderncv (casual style)? Ideally, I would love this to be a parameter for how these commands are defined, but I'd settle for figuring out how to add it to a single entry as well. Apologies in advance, I'm very new to latex code.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{grey}
\usepackage[scale=.75]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\cventry{year1--year2}{Some text.}{More Text.}{A lot of really loooooooooooooooooooooooong text that moves to the next line.}{}{}
\end{document}


Welcome to tex.sx.  You're more likely to get a usable answer if you provide a small compilable example that shows the environment in which this adjustment is wanted.  It should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

You might look up \hangindent and \hangafter.

I've tried both those a few different ways, but they don't seem to affect \cvitem or \cventry. It might be that these commands are internally specified with parameters that override \hangindent as this post suggests, but I can't seem to find where they're actually specified or how to modify them internally.
